# Function type object argument assignability in typescript

Tags: typescript

Apparently when assigning a value to a function type, the argument types should be an exact match. For example assigning a function with type:

```
(arg: {prop: string}) => void
```

to a variable with type:

```
(arg: object) => void
```

will throw error that:

> Type '(arg: {prop: string;}) => void' is not assignable to type '(arg: object) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'arg' and 'arg' are incompatible.
> Property 'prop' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ prop: string; }'

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMZQLxQBQEMBOBzALigHsAjAKwiWAEo0A+KAN2IEsATAbgFgAoPpMQQBnYFABmARjSZchKAG8oYHMTBFROVgjxQAvnVSMFenv16CRY8QCYi8ZDKmcgA)

Any help or explanation about the purpose of this behavior is appreciated, why typescript does not accept any object type for arguments with type `object` in this scenario?

Comment: Because type `object` doesn't guarantee there is key `prop`. [This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMZQLxQBQEMBOBzALigHsAjAKwiWAEo0A+KAN2IEsATAbgFgAoPpMQQBnYFABmARjSZchKAG8oYHMTBFROVgjxQAvnVSMFenv17sqAG1zRBIseIAqEUUXjI+fZ6+AYTdAD0gVDAABaswlCRUADuxDgA1tq6pHCO0ggQEOzKqmBxrOGhYdCgkFCaKVBpYuEx4ogoMQC2kcLVKmpQWAi5CMRQEDiqOF689qISAEzuTTJSZnxAA)

Comment: but isnt' that the purpose of type `object`? to accept any object. because for example here `const v:object = { prop: '' };`, any object is accepted for variable `v`

Comment: I think `object` is like `any` because almost everything is js is object exception for some primitives [See this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0BcMQCMBW9iwLwzHgHcYARAQwQAoBKIA). And Typescript need to make sure that your function will accept the `prop` key since object is any object if you doesn't pass the `prop` key it will throw error in runtime and typescript is trying to prevent that.

Comment: so there is no way in typescript to define a function type to accept all functions with object argument type?

Comment: what I need is a function type like `(arg1: object, arg2: object) => void` that accepts any function like `(arg1: {k: string}, arg2: {k: number}) => void`

Comment: There is a way to accept any object and that way is to use `object` or `Record<string, any>` but `f1` is not compatible with `Func` because `Func` accept every object including empty object but `f1` doesn't accept empty object so the type is not compatible.

Comment: Can you add a use cases using typescript playground?

Comment: I think your example is not exactly what I mean, even using `Record<string, any>` does not make a difference in my example because it doesn't address the main compalin of typescript here

Comment: Yes its the same. `object` and `Record<string, any>` is same but `Record<string, any>` is stricter because it will only accept string as key.

Comment: I already put ts playground in question description, that's exactly what I need

Comment: I mean why do you want to do that.

Comment: I have a function that accepts functions as its arguments and these arguments need to have signature like `(arg: object) => void`, which means any function that has object argument

Comment: Like this `(callback: ((arg: object)=>void))=>void`?

Comment: yes, sth like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255244/discussion-between-kennarddh-and-erfan-azary).

Comment: btw this `(callback: ((arg: object)=>void))=>void` is the same thing and has same problem

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMZQLxQBRIIYBtcBG2SA1gFyYbYBOA5hQPYEBWESwAlKgHwBuDASwAmHDmm5R+wgNwBYAFAKkDBAGdgUAGZl4yNJiQEuEgN4BfBUpXqtAJgpU6ZE2GoMwFddQEJaZsTySgkL6GAGmForymhiathzSQA

Comment: Ok its still the same problem because you can never convert object to {prop: string} because typescript cannot make sure that object contains prop key.

Comment: yeah, right. So just to wrap this up, I think the only way to proceed with this approach is to use dangerous `any` type instead of object just for this specific case. It should be fine as long as it's only in a restricted part of code

Comment: Functions are *contravariant* in their parameter types, at least with `--strictFunctionTypes` enabled (see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types)).  This is for safety reasons.  Yes, every `{prop: string}` is an `object`, but *not* every function that accepts any `{prop: string}` argument  is one that accepts any `object` argument.   See other linked q/a for more info

Comment: thank you @jcalz, this completely resolves doubts on this